# Google Sheets COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I have a Google Sheet with a column of Names and some columns of Values
I also have a column of total available Names

This Sheet is connected to a Google Form and i need to check if users have filled any value in Values Columns

I need a formula that indicates if there are any missing names (of total available Names) from the NAMES Column and also if a Name appears give a warn that this name has no values in its row

Here is a screenshot of what i mean
[image]

Here is a shared form to give it a try
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N2CCD7MdKBO0faj8akfdtX-K_JZ6o7hD0tZSVfnbrAs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with this formula:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(J3:J,J3:J<>""),{C3:C,IF(D3:D&E3:E&F3:F&G3:G<>"","OK","Missing Values")},2,FALSE),"Missing Name"))`

This looks up every value in the full names list (`FILTER`ed to remove blanks) within a virtual array with names from form submissions in column 1 and a concatenation of all form VALUES per row in column 2.

If a name from the full list is not found within the form submissions, `VLOOKUP` throws an error, which is replaced with "Missing Name" by the `IFERROR` outer wrap.

If a name is found and the concatenation of all values fields is not blank (i.e., if there is even one value present in that row), "OK" is returned. Otherwise, "Missing Values" is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use COUNTA. It worked for me in your testfile.
COUNTIF counts numbers, COUNTA also counts text.

`=IF(COUNTA(D3:G3)<>0,"OK", "MISSING NAME")`

Comment: Thanks for your time Mike. That's not exactly what i need as i want to first check the appearance of a name from"Total Names" . If the name appears i need to check if any values exist in its row. That's why i first used COUNTIF

Comment: Glad I could help :)